# Firebase Notification token issue

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, firebase

I am trying to implement a firebase notification using Eclipse IDE.When i run the app i have to receive a token but im not getting any token in my log but i got few errors in my logcat.the FCM plugin i have implemented is in the link below.I am attaching the error file and the link of fcm i used.I will be glad if anyone try to help me to resolve the errors.Thankyou.

Link:-https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

[Here I am attaching the images of errors that i got in my logcat when i run my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78TWl.png)

Code(FCMPlugin.js):-

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function FCMPlugin() { 
console.log("FCMPlugin.js: is created");
}
// GET TOKEN //
FCMPlugin.prototype.getToken = function( success, error ){
exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'getToken', []);
}
// SUBSCRIBE TO TOPIC //
FCMPlugin.prototype.subscribeToTopic = function( topic, success, error ){
exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'subscribeToTopic', [topic]);
}
// UNSUBSCRIBE FROM TOPIC //
FCMPlugin.prototype.unsubscribeFromTopic = function( topic, success, error )                 {
exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'unsubscribeFromTopic', [topic]);
}
// NOTIFICATION CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotification = function( callback, success, error ){
FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotificationReceived = callback;
exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'registerNotification',[]);
}
// DEFAULT NOTIFICATION CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotificationReceived = function(payload){
console.log("Received push notification")
console.log(payload)
}
// FIRE READY //
exec(function(result){ console.log("FCMPlugin Ready OK") }, function(result) {   console.log("FCMPlugin Ready ERROR") }, "FCMPlugin",'ready',[]);
var fcmPlugin = new FCMPlugin();
module.exports = fcmPlugin;
```

In the above code at line:1 i got an error require is not defined

Comment: Show your code,i'll try to solve your issue.

Comment: Make sure you have ‘google-services.json’ for Android or ‘GoogleService-Info.plist’ for iOS in your Cordova project root folder.

Comment: The code i used is in the above link.@RishabhMahatha

Comment: I added the google-services.json for android only in my cordova project folder @HassanALi

Comment: Are you building your through some build service or building your application locally ?

Comment: I am building it using eclipse Ide and i cant use android studio according to my requirement@ HassanALi

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the link cordova plugin fcm which i have implemented and also the image of errors i got in my log  @FrankvanPuffelen